# Futures basis (Bond) optimal delivery

Tags: fixed-income, bond, arbitrage, basis

i have a confusion regarding how the basis converges in a couple of scenarios. Lets assume I am long UST CTD Basis

1. Say the curve is upward sloping:
   optimally, i would choose to make delivery of the bond at the last notice date (say last trade date is 1week before the last notice date).
   I would choose not to deliver at the last trading date as I can benefit from +ve carry for the next 1 week (+ don't want to squander my end of month option). Aside from the fact that the futures price ~ (Spot - 1w carry - EOM option PV)/CF, at the last trading date, can i say anything else about the basis (net of carry)? At this point it should probably just be positive a few ticks?
2. Say the yield curve is downward sloping:
   There is a trade off between the carry and the end of month (EOM) optionality. So there are 2 scenarios, say:
   a). -ve Carry outweights the optionality lost.
   My optimal strategy here would be to save the -ve carry and deliver as soon as possible. Say this date is the last trading date of the contract. In this scenario as the negative 1w Carry more than offsets the EOM option PV => the converted futures price > spot price (therefore, basis is -ve) at the last trading date. But how can basis be -ve? As I can arbitrage this if I had no position by buying the CTD and selling a future and immediately delivering into this (this it self would push the basis back to 0).
   b). -ve Carry doesn't outweight the optionality lost.
   This would revert to something similar to point 1.